# Resources not found by Microsoft Edge, why?

Tags: html, apache, microsoft-edge

I am having a weird issue and I don't know how to fix it. I am calling this URL: `http://rperez.local` and for some reason some resources are not being found.

This problem is **ONLY** present in Microsoft Edge. I have test the same URL in Chrome, Firefox and even Internet Explorer 11 and it works as should be so I don't know where the problem is in this case.

Here is the error coming up in the browser console:

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://rperez.local/js/mmi_js/scripts.js?1491850831
dashboard (49,1)
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://rperez.local/images/icons/24x24/mail.png
dashboard (140,1)
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://rperez.local/images/icons/24x24/office-building.png
dashboard (106,1)
...
GET - http://rperez.local/images/icons/16x16/navigate_open.png
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
jquery-1.12.4.min.js (4,16632)
```

The funny thing here is, if for example I call this URL: `http://rperez.local/images/icons/16x16/navigate_open.png` in a tab using Microsoft Edge, I did see the image, but from the page isn't working.

I am using Apache but there isn't any rule blocking this response, in fact if it's working in the rest of the browsers and I can access the image from outside the page something else is going on here.

Does any one run into the same issue? Any workaround?

Comment: any luck? am also getting same problem